# How do I combine a template reference variable with ngIf?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

```
<div *ngIf="true" myHighlight #tRefVar="myHighlight"></div>
<div>tRefVar is {{tRefVar.foo}}</div>
```

Even though the `*ngIf` is true, I get a `Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined`. If I remove the `*ngIf`, it works fine!

I tried using the Elvis operator `tRefVar?.foo`, which resolved the error, but then it never updates with the value.

https://plnkr.co/edit/5rsXygxK1sBbbkYdobjn?p=preview

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can simply use `[ngStyle]="{'display': showElement ? 'block' : 'none'}"` or use any other default display option (flex, inline ...)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As Tobias Bosch said

> A variable declared inside of an *ngIf cannot be used outside of the
>   *ngIf

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6179#issuecomment-233374700

> Only the opposite way (i.e. declare a variable inside of *ngIf and use
>   it outside of *ngIf) is not working, and **won't work by design.**

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6179#issuecomment-233579605

### Why is it so?

**1) Without *ngIf**

Let's see at this template

```
<h2 myHighlight #tRefVar="myHighlight">tRefVar is {{tRefVar.foo}}</h2>
<div>tRefVar is {{tRefVar?.foo}}</div>
```

angular will create the following `viewDefinition` for that:

```
function View_App_0(_l) {
  return jit_viewDef1(0,[(_l()(),jit_textDef2(null,['\n      '])),(_l()(),jit_elementDef3(0,
      null,null,2,'h2',[['myHighlight','']],null,null,null,null,null)),jit_directiveDef4(16384,
      [['tRefVar',4]],0,jit_HighlightDirective5,[jit_ElementRef6],null,null),(_l()(),
      jit_textDef2(null,['tRefVar is ',''])),(_l()(),jit_textDef2(null,['\n      '])),
      (_l()(),jit_elementDef3(0,null,null,1,'div',[],null,null,null,null,null)),(_l()(),
          jit_textDef2(null,['tRefVar is ',''])),(_l()(),jit_textDef2(null,['\n  ']))],
      null,function(_ck,_v) {
        var currVal_0 = jit_nodeValue7(_v,2).foo;
        _ck(_v,3,0,currVal_0);
        var currVal_1 = ((jit_nodeValue7(_v,2) == null)? null: jit_nodeValue7(_v,2).foo);
        _ck(_v,6,0,currVal_1);
      });
}
```

[image]

there is no embedded view here. All in one `View_App_0`. And we can see here our expression `{{tRefVar?.foo}}`

```
var currVal_1 = ((jit_nodeValue7(_v,2) == null)? null: jit_nodeValue7(_v,2).foo);
```

it takes value from node with index 2

```
jit_directiveDef4(16384,
  [['tRefVar',4]],0,jit_HighlightDirective5,[jit_ElementRef6],null,null),(_l()(),
  jit_textDef2(null,['tRefVar is ','']))
```

that declared in the same view

**2) With *ngIf**

Then let's change template as follows

```
<h2 *ngIf="true" myHighlight #tRefVar="myHighlight">tRefVar is {{tRefVar.foo}}</h2>
<div>tRefVar is {{tRefVar?.foo}}</div>
```

The output will be the following

```
function View_App_1(_l) {
  return jit_viewDef1(0,[(_l()(),jit_elementDef2(0,null,null,2,'h2',[['myHighlight',
      '']],null,null,null,null,null)),jit_directiveDef3(16384,[['tRefVar',4]],0,jit_HighlightDirective4,
      [jit_ElementRef5],null,null),(_l()(),jit_textDef6(null,['tRefVar is ','']))],
      null,function(_ck,_v) {
        var currVal_0 = jit_nodeValue7(_v,1).foo;
        _ck(_v,2,0,currVal_0);
      });
}
function View_App_0(_l) {
  return jit_viewDef1(0,[(_l()(),jit_textDef6(null,['\n'])),(_l()(),jit_anchorDef8(16777216,
      null,null,1,null,View_App_1)),jit_directiveDef3(16384,null,0,jit_NgIf9,[jit_ViewContainerRef10,
      jit_TemplateRef11],{ngIf:[0,'ngIf']},null),(_l()(),jit_textDef6(null,['\n'])),
      (_l()(),jit_elementDef2(0,null,null,1,'div',[],null,null,null,null,null)),(_l()(),
          jit_textDef6(null,['tRefVar is ',''])),(_l()(),jit_textDef6(null,['\n  ']))],
      function(_ck,_v) {
        var currVal_0 = true;
        _ck(_v,2,0,currVal_0);
      },function(_ck,_v) {
        var _co = _v.component;
        var currVal_1 = ((_co.tRefVar == null)? null: _co.tRefVar.foo);
        _ck(_v,5,0,currVal_1);
      });
}
```

[image]

Angular created embedded view `View_App_1` apart to `View_App_0` . And our expression `{{tRefVar?.foo}}` has turned into

```
var currVal_1 = ((_co.tRefVar == null)? null: _co.tRefVar.foo);
```

it just becames component property because there is no node that will reference to this template variable in `View_App_0`. It's gone to embedded view `View_App_1`

```
var currVal_0 = jit_nodeValue7(_v,1).foo;
```

So we cannot refer to template variable that has been declared in embedded view outside of embedded view.

**How to solve it?**

1) Use visibility flag like `[hidden]` or css class instead of `*ngIf`

2) Move your expression inside embedded view where `tRefVar` is declared

```
<ng-container *ngIf="true">
  <h2 myHighlight #tRefVar="myHighlight">tRefVar is {{tRefVar.foo}}</h2>
  <div>tRefVar is {{tRefVar?.foo}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

3) Use `@ViewChild` because it will represent component property. Or use `@ViewChildren`

Comment: Why do you suggest using `ng-container` instead of `ng-template` with `ngIf` in the solution #2? If both are possible, what are consideration to choose between them in this case?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov I showed sugared version of ngIf there because it was easy for everyone to undestrand this well know syntax. You can use `<ng-template [ngIf]` instead and it event better because it doesn't create additional comment node

Comment: Got it, thank you, especially for mentioning about the comment node! Just checking what are differences between the two options due to lack of my experience here.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using Angular 8 you can solve this issue by adding a view child reference and setting the static value to `false`.

Example template code:

```
<button type="button" (click)="eventsTable.someMethod()">Click Me!</button>
<div *ngIf="someValue" #eventsTable >
    SHIBAMBO!
</div>
```

Component Code:

```
export class EventsComponent {
    @ViewChild('eventsTable', {static: false}) eventsTable: Table;

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.eventsTable)
    }
}
```

In Angular 9, `false` will be the default value.

Answer (score 3):

`<div *ngIf="true" myHighlight #tRefVar="myHighlight"></div>`
Here you should note that `*ngIf` is a *syntactic sugar*(shortcut) to define a `ng-template`, So that actually evaluates to

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="true">
  <h2 myHighlight #tRefVar="myHighlight">Hello {{name}}, tRefVar is {{tRefVar.foo}}</h2>
</ng-template>
<div>tRefVar is {{tRefVar?.foo}}</div>
```

Note that `#tRefVar` is accessible by Child(`div` here) and itself(`ng-template` here).
The second `<div>` is not a sibling to the `<div>` where Template reference variable is present.
<sub>More explained [here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-asterisk--prefix)</sub>

---

The behavior is expected as the Template reference variable can be referenced by Child/Sibling elements.

Comment: My reference to `tRefVar.foo` *is* still in a sibling of the `ng-template` though right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think @lexith is right, [You can refer to a template reference variable anywhere in the template](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars)

Comment: @adamdport https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13516#issuecomment-267546981

Answer (score 0):

You could use for example `ng-container` and set your `ngIf` conditional there, which makes `tRevVar` accessible like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="true">
     <h2 myHighlight #tRefVar="myHighlight">Hello {{name}}, tRefVar is {{tRefVar.foo}}</h2>
     <div>tRefVar is {{tRefVar?.foo}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/cqrsDVGwa90o1FGWgE22?p=preview

There are probably more ways to make it work, but you have to be more specific then, what you want to do with it.

Hope i could help.

---

To answer the question in your comment "*Shouldn't it update tRefVar after that first tick though?"*:

No, because it's undefined. You'll have the same outcome if you declare an object in your component (but leave it undefined) and add a property to it. The elvis operator doesn't help there.

```
myObj: any;

ngOnInit() {
    myObj.text = 'my Text';
}

<div>{{ myObj?.text }}</div>
```

This won't work, but this would be working:

```
myObj: any = {};

ngOnInit() {
    myObj.text = 'my Text';
}

<div>{{ myObj?.text }}</div>
```

---

Edited my answer again and removed the confusing explanation which was plain wrong. thanks yurzui, finally got what you meant. needed a night of sleep for it.

Comment: `that because of your ngIf which takes a tick of time to evaluate` I think it is just unavailable outside `ng-template` block https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642487/angular2-ngif-and-local-template-variables https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16262

Comment: But i didn't change it. So no, that's not the case (at least not anymore it seems). Added a plunkr.

Comment: You inserted `{{tRefVar?.foo}}` inside `ng-template`

Comment: @lexith Shouldn't it update `tRefVar` after that first tick though?

Comment: `that because of your ngIf which takes a tick of time to evaluate` Here is this case https://plnkr.co/edit/pkF48jOGNRbX2u9RdL4e?p=preview

Comment: See my comment to the other answer. It's true that `*ngIf` is a shortcut for `ng-template [ngIf]=""` but this isn't the reason the value can't be accessed like he did.

Comment: You forgot to refer to me in comments :)

Comment: @yurzui keep forgetting that, sorry ;)

Comment: I got what you want to say. What about *ngFor? https://plnkr.co/edit/qrIpgbTGVIAcQQTNv3M7?p=preview See also this explanation https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16262#issuecomment-296835766

Answer (score 0):

As given in the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44811477/5181313) by @lexith, Because you're using `*ngIf` the corresponding template variable is not defined at the time. We can avoid this confusion by modifying the code
`<div *ngIf="true" myHighlight #tRefVar="myHighlight"></div>` with
`<div [hidden]=false myHighlight #tRefVar="myHighlight"></div>` and that will work.

---

Final code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 [hidden]=false myHighlight #tRefVar="myHighlight">Hello {{name}}, tRefVar is {{tRefVar.foo}}</h2>
      <div>tRefVar is {{tRefVar?.foo}}</div>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

[Modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/82vXHqeLLfnel7BCvPc5?p=preview)