# Show ion-button when *ngIf does not exist

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I have an array of cards that displays download buttons.  I wish to hide the download button in the first `div` if I have already downloaded and saved the data to the database and the second `div` then displays.

```html
<ion-card *ngFor="let data of itemList.list let i = index">
  <ion-card-content>

    <div> <!-- I want this to display if *ngIf="n == data.task does not display -->
      <ion-button (click)="saveData(data.link)" >Download for offline use</ion-button>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let n of loop"> <!-- loops through keys in database -->
      <div *ngIf="n == data.task"> <!-- if data.task key exists the buttons display -->
        <div class = "linkButtons">
          <ion-button (click)="openForm(data.Type, data.task)">&nbsp;&nbsp;Open&nbsp;&nbsp;</ion-button>
          <ion-button (click)="syncData()">Sync</ion-button>
          <ion-button (click)="deleteAudit( n )">Delete</ion-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't accomplish what you're trying to do with the template only, you can learn more about why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44812573/6275781).

What you can do is cache the results in your component with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
dataTasks = new Map<any, boolean>()
taskEquals(data: any, n: any) {
    if (!this.dataTasks.get(data)) {
        this.dataTasks.set(data, data.task == n)
    }
    return data.task == n
}

hasTask(data: any) {
    return !!this.dataTasks.get(data)
}
```

Then your template code can use these functions:

```html
<ion-card *ngFor="let data of itemList.list let i = index">
  <ion-card-content>

    <div *ngIf="hasTask(data) == false">
      <ion-button (click)="saveData(data.link)">Download for offline use</ion-button>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let n of loop">
      <div *ngIf="taskEquals(data, n)">
        <div class = "linkButtons">
          <ion-button (click)="openForm(data.Type, data.task)">&nbsp;&nbsp;Open&nbsp;&nbsp;</ion-button>
          <ion-button (click)="syncData()">Sync</ion-button>
          <ion-button (click)="deleteAudit( n )">Delete</ion-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

---

An alternative solution without using `Map` would be to assign the result to a property on the `data` object.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [`ngIf` with `else`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else) (I have also changed the order of your template a bit; I hope it makes sense):

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let data of itemList.list">
  <ion-card-content>

    <div *ngIf="n === data.task; else linkButtons">
      <ion-button (click)="saveData(data.link)">
        Download for offline use
      </ion-button>
    </div>

    <ng-template #linkButtons>
      <div *ngFor="let n of loop">
        <div class="linkButtons">
          <ion-button (click)="openForm(data.Type, data.task)">Open</ion-button>
          <ion-button (click)="syncData()">Sync</ion-button>
          <ion-button (click)="deleteAudit(n)">Delete</ion-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>

  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: This answer did not work for me as i still need *ngFor="let data of itemList.list let i = index" . to list through my audits. The *ngFor="let n of loop" to list through saved keys.  But your answer is really good at explaining using ngIf with else so I marked your answer as useful

Comment: Glad my answer is at least a bit helpful :) And indeed, I was not totally sure about your requirements.

Comment: My requirements are a little complex so I will be offering bounty for this.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a local boolean flag in data object to check if data has been downloaded, the `saveDate(data)` function will also need modifications:

```html
<ion-card *ngFor="let data of itemList.list let i = index">
  <ion-card-content>

    <div *ngIf="data.downloaded">
      <ion-button (click)="saveData(data)" >Download for offline use</ion-button>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let n of loop"> <!-- loops through keys in database -->
      <div *ngIf="n == data.task"> <!-- if data.task key exists the buttons display -->
        <div class = "linkButtons">
          <ion-button (click)="openForm(data.Type, data.task)">&nbsp;&nbsp;Open&nbsp;&nbsp;</ion-button>
          <ion-button (click)="syncData()">Sync</ion-button>
          <ion-button (click)="deleteAudit( n )">Delete</ion-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

```js
saveData(data){
    // remaining logic
    data.downloaded = !data.downloaded;
}
```