# How to display template reference variables within elements with *ngIf in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom, swagger-ui

I want to render a JSON file with Swagger UI. However, the API documentation should be displayed within a  element that contains *ngIf. If I execute the code shown, the API documentation is not displayed, but if I omit *ngIf, everything works.

```
  @ViewChild('customerapidocumentation', { static: true })
  custApiDocElement: ElementRef | undefined;

 ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    const apiDocumentation = this.api;
    const ui = SwaggerUI({
      spec: apiDocumentation,
      domNode: this.custApiDocElement?.nativeElement
    });
  }
```

```
 <div *ngIf="docu">
      <div #customerapidocumentation id="customer-api-documentation"></div>
 </div>
```

I also tried it with {static: false} and ngAfterViewInit, but that didn't work either.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811132/how-do-i-combine-a-template-reference-variable-with-ngif

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz for this?

Comment: `static:true` it's **only** when the template reference variable is not under a *ngIf. This "argument" say to Angular **not** check if exist else at very first stages of the component (It's the reason you can use in ngOnInit). That's: only check if exist **one time**

Comment: @LogicBlower I tried the suggestions in the other post, but they don't work either. For example, if I use [hidden]="!docu" instead of *ngIf="docu", it has the same effect as if I just omit *ngIf completely. If an API is present, it is displayed with Swagger UI, but if docu is undefined, I get errors in the console, which does not happen with *ngIf.